# Most Proficient Way to Serve a Headless Webkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, webkit

I want to simply boot up a Headless WebKit browser using Node.js -- Ideally, it will be light weight, have a node-api for opening a url (...etc), but most importantly: **I don't want to depend on** Python, xCode, ..etc. I just want an `npm install everythingINeedForNodeWebkitModule`, preferably OS-agnostic. Pretty straight forward, but hopeful.

All I need is something like:

```
var wk = require('webkit');
var URL = 'http://localhost:3000/index.html';
wk.open(URL, function(){
    var socketIO = require('socketIO');
    socketIO.emit('helloWebkit', {data: {el: 'div#id.class'}});
    socketIO.on('hello', function(textNode){
        console.log('got it', textNode === 'hello');
    });
});
wk.close();
```

Like I said, pretty straight forward, but hopefully light and singularly-packaged (hopefully pure Node.js).

Is there any module out there I can use? Is it easy to create my own Node wrapper for WebKit? Can I just open a webkit using Node in anyway?

I want to note that this is not for unit testing, its strictly for interacting with a webkit's window.

Comment: I don't get it, why would you need a headless browser to use socket IO with a real browser? Do you need to parse something that could only be done in a browser enviroment? If it's just markup, you can use something like Cheerio etc ?

Comment: latest node-webkit v0.8.4 fix a performance bug on OSX. It should fix your issue.

Comment: adeneo, I will be dealing with extremely classical data, so we are experimenting with getting data by `tagName`, `className`, etc.

Comment: @adeneo, The code above is quite obviously just an example.

Comment: @Pacerier - and it's quite obviously three years old? Anyway, I realize it's just an example, but an example that uses websockets and SocketIO to communicate with a headless browser that can't really communicate back, makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a library like PhantomJS?

http://phantomjs.org/

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://example.com', function() {
    page.render('example.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Thx, I've been dabbling with phantomjs and spooky, but its somewhat heavy and difficult to serve in some cases without using the async lib. Kim T, is this simply an `npm install`, cause I seemed to be missing dependencies...? Though, this sounds like my best shot. Still holding out for a raw webkit implementation though.

Comment: The original version is not a node package. You can install using brew:
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
brew update
brew install phantomjs

Alternatively you can install someone's wrapper using:
npm install phantomjs